# Physics and mathematics books

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I've just been accepted into Aeronautical engineering bachelors. Since I finished high school 2 years ago, I would like to refresh my memory on mathematics and physics. What would be some good books, that would have a wide summary of the subjects. possibly with some exercises.